# Combinatorics: number of fruit baskets of size $n$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I improved a little but that expression about even number of strawberries prevented me to solve this.

How many fruit baskets are there, which should include $n$ fruits with up to 3 bananas, an even number of strawberries, and any number of pineapples and grapes?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Not clea and you should add your thoughts with the question.

Comment: Do you mean: How many integer solutions are there to
$$
x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = n
$$
with $x_1 \leq 3$? The answer is a function of $n$.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

essentially you are looking for the number of non-negative integer solutions to the equation:
$$
x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_4=n,
$$
where $x_1\le3$.

The solution of the problem is:
$$
[x^n]\frac{1+x+x^2+x^3}{(1-x^2)(1-x)^2}=[x^n]\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^3},
$$
where $[x^n]$ is the coefficient extractor function which gives the coefficient at $x^n$ in the series expansion of the following expression. With help of generalized binomial theorem you can even obtain an explicit expression in terms of binomial coefficients.